# Should I add a note for recruiters in my LinkedIn public profile?

Tags: communication, job-offer, linkedin

I'm a lucky person with skills and experience that are currently in demand in my region (working in IT in France, not in Paris ;-)
My LinkedIn resume is up-to-date, and the "Looking for new opportunities" checkbox is currently unticked. However, I still receive *many* invitations from recruiters just saying

> Hey, I've got a GREAT opportunity for you. Wanna chat ?

Sometimes, there's more detail :

> Hello, my name is [Recruiter], I work at the HR for [company] and I'm looking for someone with your skills for [very short job description]. Call me !

I have no problem being contacted by HR people, since this is what LinkedIn is for, but such lame messages look like spam to me. I'd like to know *way more* than that, even at the first contact, before replying. Actually, a detailed job offer would be perfect :

- description of job
- tools, technologies
- location
- team size
- internal practices / tools
- salary
- ...

But I guess the 1st contact message must also be short to attract and keep the reader's attention.
I'm considering adding a "note to recruiters" in my public profile saying "Give me details or I won't reply" (in a *much nicer* way than this ;-).

Would that be wise ?

Comment: I'm confused. You have the "looking for new opportunities" checkbox unchecked, yet you're asking about how to use LinkedIn as a job search tool? Why not use the built-in functionality? It allows to to advertise that you're looking, as well as specify interests (industries, etc). It's a good way to give recruiters some basic info about what you're looking for. Of course, many will ignore it and spam you anyways...

Comment: @dwizum My experience with checking the "looking for new opportunities" box and leaving a note for recruiters describing the sort of role I'm seeking is that **0%** of recruiters who contacted me had read it, and none of the opportunities they approached me with fit what I said I was looking for.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> *Would that be wise ?*

Maybe

> *Would that be useful ?*

Unfortunately, no.

As you can already tell from the category of the received messages, they are mostly blind attempt at communication and trying their "luck" at getting a response. They are not targeted communication, and anything you put in your note is not going to affect them, since they are not reading your bio / profile anyways.

Answer (score 3):

What you can do is make a generic template message that you can send to recruiters you are interested in upon initial contact. This will save your time.

Like:

Hi, Thank you for contacting me.

I am interested in knowing more details about the position.
Please let me know about the

- description of job
- tools, technologies
- location
- team size
- internal practices / tools
- salary

in detail.

Thanks,
Noob

Answer (score 1):

You can, but it likely wont help. For a few years, my LinkedIn headline was literally:

> "Not currently responding to recruiters, please give my inbox a break."

It didn't change anything, the constant bombardment continued. Since then I've changed my headline to something more professional, and just stopped looking at my messages.

Answer (score 0):

> Would that be wise ?

You would think that it would, but most of those messages you are receiving are likely the result of some automated process that searches for specific keywords and sends messages accordingly.

For the few recruiters that actually take the time to read profiles such a message would be beneficial but unfortunately LinkedIn is full of these "robo recruiters" so it will do little to stop the spam.